# What does “[sdist]” mean in PIP's list of outdated packages?

Tags: python, pip, pypi

Suddenly, all Python packages reported as out of date by pip with

```
pip list --outdated
```

indicate `[sdist]`, as in

```
awscli (Current: 1.7.19 Latest: 1.7.20 [sdist])
botocore (Current: 0.100.0 Latest: 0.101.0 [sdist])
jmespath (Current: 0.6.1 Latest: 0.6.2 [sdist])
plotly (Current: 1.6.14 Latest: 1.6.15 [sdist])
```

what does `[sdist]` mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In python packaging terms, "sdist" stands for "source distribution" and it's counterpart "bdist" stands for "binary distribution".

Along with those distribution types there's also the older "egg" and the newer egg-like distribution called "wheel".

In this case it's telling you that the newer version of your packages will be installed as a source distribution. If a binary distribution would be installed, you'd see `[wheel]` instead.

This is a [new feature](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2475), as of pip version [6.1.0](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/news.html).

Comment: So in this case it is (*probably*) saying that all of these packages are currently only available as "sdist"? Is this a new feature of PIP (I never saw this before)?

Comment: It was a recent change to pip: https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/news.html under 6.1.0 (2015-04-07). "Display format of latest package when using pip list --outdated. (PR #2475)"